# Multilevel Navbar dropdown in next.js

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js, frontend, blur

I'm encountering an issue while implementing a nested dropdown in Next.js using **Next UI** version `2.2.9.` When I click on the top-level button of the dropdown, the sublevel contents briefly appear for less than a second, and then the entire dropdown closes, rendering it unclickable. I'm unable to perform any actions. Seeking assistance to resolve this problem. Thank you!

```
   `<Dropdown backdrop="blur">
      <DropdownTrigger>
        <Button variant="light">
          Process Team
        </Button>
      </DropdownTrigger>
      <DropdownMenu variant="light" aria-label="Static Actions">
        <DropdownItem>

          <Dropdown>

            <DropdownTrigger>
              <Button variant="light">
                Member
              </Button>
            </DropdownTrigger>

            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem className="text-black">List All Cases</DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem className="text-black">Reassign Cases</DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>

          </Dropdown>

        </DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
```

`

[This is what is did using the sample code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YoHG.gif)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> I'm encountering an issue while implementing a nested dropdown in Next.js using Next UI version 2.2.9...

**Possible Cause :**

> By default `closeOnSelect` prop is `true` which causes the parent dropdown to close.

**Solution :**

> Use Dropdown Prop `closeOnSelect`, pass value to it as `false`.

change from

> `<Dropdown backdrop="blur">`

to

> `<Dropdown backdrop="blur" closeOnSelect={false}>`

```
<Dropdown backdrop="blur" closeOnSelect={false}>
    <DropdownTrigger>
        <Button variant="light">
            Process Team
        </Button>
    </DropdownTrigger>
    <DropdownMenu variant="light" aria-label="Static Actions">
        <DropdownItem>

            <Dropdown>

                <DropdownTrigger>
                    <Button variant="light">
                        Member
                    </Button>
                </DropdownTrigger>

                <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownItem className="text-black">List All Cases</DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem className="text-black">Reassign Cases</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>

            </Dropdown>

        </DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

*Similarly if you have many nesting then pass `closeOnSelect={false}` for every parent.*

**When you have more levels :**

```
<Dropdown backdrop="blur" closeOnSelect={false}>
    <DropdownTrigger>
        <Button variant="light">
            GrandParent
        </Button>
    </DropdownTrigger>
    <DropdownMenu variant="light" aria-label="Static Actions">
        <DropdownItem>
            <Dropdown backdrop="blur" closeOnSelect={false}>
                <DropdownTrigger>
                    <Button variant="light">
                        Parent
                    </Button>
                </DropdownTrigger>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownItem className="text-black">
                        <Dropdown>
                            <DropdownTrigger>
                                <Button variant="light">
                                    Child
                                </Button>
                            </DropdownTrigger>
                            <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem className="text-black">Child 1</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu>
                        </Dropdown>
                    </DropdownItem>

                </DropdownMenu>

            </Dropdown>

        </DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

> You may also use `shouldCloseOnInteractOutside` prop to enable functionality of closing dropdown when user clicks anywhere outside of it. As it will be helpful to close multilevel dropdown.

```
shouldCloseOnInteractOutside={()=> true}
```

> Also, button width is not 100% you can use Button Prop `fullWidth` & pass it Boolean true to make it 100%.

```
<Button fullWidth={true} variant="light">
```

**Please read :**

1. **Dropdown Props :** https://nextui.org/docs/components/dropdown#dropdown-props *(scroll to bottom of the page)*
2. **Dropdown Events shouldCloseOnInteractOutside** : https://nextui.org/docs/components/dropdown#dropdown-events
3. **Button Props** : https://nextui.org/docs/components/button#button-props

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment. If this answer solved your problem you may mark it as answer.***

Comment: Hello, the provided solution resolved my problem. Additionally, I'm interested in enabling the dropdown onHover effect. Could you please guide me on implementing the placement variable to position the child dropdown on the right side of the parent?

Furthermore, I'd like to understand how to automatically close the parent dropdown when the child is clicked.